# how to display amount with currency format in mvc3

Tags: razor

I have created a table for tax ranges. Now I want to display the amounts formatted like so: `$100,000`.  How can I do this?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

You could try this format, and replace amount with custom value.

```
@string.Format("{0:C}", amount);
```

Comment: any clue why its adding ¤ character in front of every value ?

Comment: @Adrian Might be a culture setting. It's a sign that denotes an unspecified currency.

Comment: @Frunk Yes, that was it. Sorry for not updating my comment :)

Comment: or use `@amount.ToString("C")`

Answer (score 21):

You could add this in your model, the currency symbol will be displayed anytime you reference that field

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:C}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    public decimal DebitAmount { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 1):

Or shorter version `@amount.ToString("C")`